# Angular 8 test ngOnInit not calling service method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

So I'm creating a test to check if my `agreementComponent` method `ngOnInit` is calling `operatorService.getOperators()`.

So far I've managed to create something like this:

```
import {AgreementComponent} from './agreement.component';
import {async, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {ActivatedRoute, convertToParamMap} from '@angular/router';
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';
import {OperatorService} from '../../../services/operator.service';
import {of} from 'rxjs/internal/observable/of';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {AgreementService} from '../../../services/agreement.service';
import {AccountService} from '../../../services/account.service';
import {SessionService} from '../../../services/session.service';
import {SettingsService} from '../../../services/settings.service';

export class MockOperatorService {
  getOperators() {
    return of({data: 'someVal'});
  }
}

export class MockAgreementService {
  getAgreementdraft() {
    return of({data: 'someVal'});
  }
}

export class MockAccountService {
  getFeeAccounts() {
    return of({data: 'someVal'});
  }
}

export class MockSessionService {
  getSession() {
    return of({data: 'someVal'});
  }
}

export class MockSettingsService {
  getSettings() {
    return of({data: 'someVal'});
  }
}

describe('agreementComponent', () => {
  let component;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AgreementComponent],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        FormsModule
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue:
            {
              snapshot: {
                paramMap: convertToParamMap({agreementId: '0'})
              }
            }
        },
        {provide: OperatorService, useClass: MockOperatorService},
        {provide: AgreementService, useClass: MockAgreementService},
        {provide: AccountService, useClass: MockAccountService},
        {provide: SessionService, useClass: MockSessionService},
        {provide: SettingsService, useClass: MockSettingsService},
      ]
    });

  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AgreementComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  it('should call operators service', () => {
    spyOn(MockOperatorService.prototype, 'getOperators').and.callThrough();

    component.ngOnInit();

    expect(MockOperatorService.prototype.getOperators).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

But I'm getting `Expected spy getOperators to have been called.` I'm not sure if I created `spyOn` and called the `ngOnInit` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

Before first beforeEach block declare a variable as

```
let operatorService: OperatorService;
```

Within the beforeEach block  add this line `operatorService = TestBed.get(OperatorService);` at the bottom.

And update your test case as

```
it('should call operators service', () => {
    spyOn(operatorService, 'getOperators');

    component.ngOnInit();

    expect(operatorService.getOperators).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```